# Is there a class in slf4j similar to org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout?

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

I want to restrict the length of Exception's stacktrace in SLF4J logging framework.

Is there a class in SLF4j similar to `EnhancedPatternLayout` in log4j?

If it's not how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

SLF4J is just an API, you need so called binding. [logback](/questions/tagged/logback) is one of them and it [supports shortening stack traces](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#ex) via `%ex{short}` directive.